# Swift: Error updating UI component when using a delegate

Tags: user-interface, swift, delegation

I'm trying to update a progress bar with the progress of loading a load of values into CoreData. However, whenever I try to call an update on my progressView component, I get a fatal error stating that "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value".

The interesting thing is that this happens even if I put 'self.progressView.progress = 0.5' in the delegate method of my program - indicating that it's the progressView component it can't find rather than an issue with the value. A quick check with println also confirms the value does exist and so isn't nil. Note that if I put the 'self.progressView.progress = 0.5' statement under a function connected directly to a button, it works fine so it must be some sort of issue with the command being called from the delegate.

Can anyone work out what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks for your help.

Delegate method:

```
class ViewControllerUpdate: UIViewController, NSURLSessionDelegate, NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate, saveUpdate {

[....]

func updateStatus(status: String, progress: Float?) {
    if let percentProgress = progress? {
        self.progressView.progress = 0.5
    }
    //println(progress) - NOTE THIS IS CORRECTLY POPULATED WITH THE APPROPRIATE VALUE
}
```

Calling class:

```
protocol saveUpdate {
    func updateStatus(status:String, progress:Float?)
}
```

class sqlPullSave {

```
let classtoUpdate: saveUpdate = ViewControllerUpdate()

func saveTSVtoSQL(fromFile: NSURL) -> Int {

    //Load up the information into a Dictionary (tsv)
    //let tsvURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(fromFileName, ofType: fromFileExtension)!)
    let tsvURL: NSURL = fromFile
    let tab = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "\t")
    let tsv = CSV(contentsOfURL: tsvURL, separator: tab)
    //let defResult: AnyObject = tsv.rows[0]["Name"]!

    //let tryagain:String = AnyObjecttoString(tsv.rows[1]["Name"]!)
    //load the data into the SQLite database...
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    for a in 0..<tsv.rows.count {
        self.SQLsaveLine(self.AnyObjecttoString(tsv.rows[a]["Name"]!),
            name_l: "",
            desc: self.AnyObjecttoString(tsv.rows[a]["1"]!),
            jobTitle: self.AnyObjecttoString(tsv.rows[a]["2"]!),
            extn: self.AnyObjecttoString(tsv.rows[a]["3"]!)
        // update status
        var percentComplete: Float = (Float(a) / Float(tsv.rows.count))
        self.classtoUpdate.self.updateStatus("SQLload", progress: percentComplete)
        }
    }
    return 0
}
```

Comment: `self.classtoUpdate.self.updateStatus` ... what's for second `self` for?

Comment: Is your progress view an IBOutlet?
If so, did you remember to connect it in your storyboard?

Comment: Hi - yes it is connected up correctly. If I add another button to the form and link this directly to the same statement, the progressView updates correctly so it must be an issue with the delegate call. Also, the second 'self' - good call and I've removed it. The problem still stands though.